# Asterisk C# - Recording filename

Tags: c#, .net, asterisk

I have developed an application in C# which listens for Asterisk events and does certain actions. I am using the Asterisk.Net DLL.

I would like to know how I can get the recording file name through my application and save it to a table in my database. I realize it is a uniquely generated number but the DLL does not seem to return it.

Answer (score 0):

Almost each AMI event have uniqueid. You need catch NewExten event with Mixmonitor(or Record), and got from it filename.

Other option - from dialplan send that filename using UserEvent command.

Comment: Thanks @arheops. I have spoken to the 3rd party company who supplied the Asterisk system and they informed me that I should catch the Dial and Link events. These have the primary ID that the recording is stored with. If that fails, I will give your suggestion a go.